# Unity Mirror with Webgl socket exception error

Tags: unity-game-engine, server, unity-webgl, unity3d-mirror

> SocketException: mono-io-layer-error (0)
> at System.Net.Sockets.Socket..ctor (System.Net.Sockets.AddressFamily addressFamily, System.Net.Sockets.SocketType socketType, System.Net.Sockets.ProtocolType protocolType) [0x00000] in <00000000000000000000000000000000>:0
> (Filename: currently not available on il2cpp Line: -1)

This error pops out when im try to connect with server. I open the developer console on the Chrome and the error pops out on the console.
Why does it mention file name , am I missing a file? the server is hosted on google cloud
[image]

Previously, I added a web config file to fix my syntax error according to this link https://answers.unity.com/questions/1397472/webgl-build-when-uploaded-gives-me-this-error-unca.html

```html
<configuration>
        <system.webServer>
           <staticContent>

              <mimeMap fileExtension=".unityweb" mimeType ="TYPE/SUBTYPE" />
           </staticContent>
        </system.webServer> 
     </configuration>
```

I try to find around net and for my life I still can't find the answer!! This issue had been bugging me for days, so I appreciate for any input or ideas!

Comment: Can you add your code?

Comment: @derHugo which part of code you are concerned of? is there a possible part of code causing this issue?

Comment: Probably the code where you are using Mirror? Or is it just the built-in stuff?

Comment: @derHugo i maybe can't send the whole code here, but im using the default built in stuff for mirror, updated in my first original post

Comment: Having the exact same issue, you ever find a fix?